# Distinct javascript objects with equal properties (names)

Tags: javascript, class, oop, resharper

Even if there are no "real" objects in `javascript` I'm struggling on how to make them distinct to each other.

For example I have the two objects `Apple` and `Orange` defined like this:

```
function Apple(){
    this.name = "Apple";
}
```

and

```
function Orange(){
    this.name = "Orange";
}
```

In an `OOP` point of view, the two `name` attributes are not connected as they are properties of different classes.

My problem/question is, that when renaming the name property of the `class` Apple, ReSharper will also ask me to rename the property of class Orange.
Also pressing F12 (GOTO DEFINITION) will show me both properties.

But why? Are they defined in global scope? How can I distinct them so Orange and Apple are real different objects?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with ReSharper not with your code.
In JS objects of those classes are completely distinct: http://jsfiddle.net/16owh01o/3/

Comment: That is, unless your are calling your functions as functions and not via a constructor: `Orange(); Apple();` In this case, both would write into the global scope, as `this` would refer to the global object (usually `window`). Maybe reshaper makes assumptions about your function usage.

Comment: @nils: So anything I could try to not have them in the global scope? Not sure what you mean by `unless your are calling your functions as functions and not via a constructor`

Comment: If you use them the way Lucas S. suggested (i.e. `var myOrange = new Orange();` as opposed to just calling `Orange();`), you should be fine. This way, `this` would refer to your new Object `myOrange`.

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper cannot know in advance how you're going to use your functions "Apple" and "Orange". That's why it searches for all possible dynamic usages of some symbol. Let's consider the following example:

```js
function Apple(){
    this.name = "Apple";
}

function Orange(){
    this.name = "Orange";
}

var x = {name: "Tomato" };

Apple.call(x);

alert(x.name);

Orange.call(x);

alert(x.name);
```

If you rename one of the items named 'name' to something different, but leave the others with the name 'name', your code will become broken. So, it makes sense to rename all of them.

That's why ReSharper lists all three usages in such case, and it's up to you to decide, according to exact semantics of your code, which of them to rename and which of them to leave as is.